# how can I put particular action as I select any row of UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, row, uipickerview

I am writing code like

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    int n=row+1;
    if(row == 0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute", n];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", n];
}
```

now I want to start timer as I choose any row, like row 5 has 5 mints, so I want to start timer with 5 mints, so what should I do, How can I choose particular row and press button and timer starts for that event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future if you go onto google and type in the name of your class and "class reference" you can usually find the information you need on the apple website.

For instance, I just went onto google and typed "UIPickerView class reference" and got to here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html.

On that website if you read the description it says "The delegate must adopt the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol" and if you click there it says, under tasks:

## Responding to Row Selection –

```
pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

This is the delegate method you need to implement that will get called when the user selects a row. If you click on it it gives a little description and such.

If you go to the description then the full method is:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

so when a user selects a row this method is called and the pickerView is passed into the method automatically.

You can then get the row that user chose. If you go back a page to the UIPickerView class reference you see this:

## Selecting Rows in the View Picker

```
– selectRow:inComponent:animated:
– selectedRowInComponent:
```

The method `selectedRowInComponent:` is the one you want. So in the delegate method you can do something like this:

```
int selectedRow = (int)[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

:) Thats what I do when I want to find answers to questions like this. :)

---

Edit:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int selectedRow = (int)[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSLog(@"%i",selectedRow);
}
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but can you tell me just a line of code that will show alert message at any row?

Comment: I've edited my answer and put at the end of it what you need. That will NSLog the row the user has selected. If you want to show an alert you can by using the UIAlertView class. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: The are becomes highlighted and blue, but nothing comes in NSLog, and also used UIAlertView, but both are not working here, now what to do, check it again please

Comment: have you set your class as a uipickerview delegate and set the uipickerview's delegate property to `self`?

Comment: there was another big problem, now it is fine and working well, thanx, I have accepted your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've implemented UIPickerViewDelegate protocol, **here's Swift 5 Version of Thomas Clayson's answer:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let selectedRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    print(selectedRow)
}
```